# Google Sheets App Script: Find character location in a text & substring

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to find the location of a character (in this case a colon, ':') inside a text and then substring the text to only before the colon. I use `string.substring(starting-offset, ending-offset)` to substring the text. So basically I'm trying to make the `ending-offset` dynamic, based on the location of the colon in the text. Thanks for your help!

`string.substring(starting-offset, cellA.find(':'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

option 1) 
combination of `slice` and `indexOf` should work for you:

```
var str = 'The quick brown fox jumps:over the lazy dog.';
Logger.log(str.slice(0, str.indexOf(':')));
// expected output: "the lazy dog."
```

option 2)
use `match` + regular explressions:

```
var str = 'The quick brown fox jumps:over the lazy dog.';
Logger.log(str.match(/^(.*)\:/)[1]);
// expected output: "the lazy dog."
```

[String.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)

[String.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Dmytro! I tried your 1st solution (easier to understand for me) and it worked.